# Unity Ads not showing rewarded ads

Tags: admob, unityads

I have set up Admob in my unity game and I'm using unity ads as meditation for rewarded video.

**Problem** is that rewarded video is not showing at all.

If I go to unity ads dashboard and set VIDEO as default then it shows VIDEO. If I go and set REWARDEDVIDEO as default then it doesn't work.

Also, if I set FORCE TESTMODE ON  and VIDEO as default, then it shows test video that is skippable after 5 sec; if I set FORCE TESTMODE ON and REWARDEDVIDEO as default, then it shows nothing (if I set FORCE TESTMODE OFF and REWARDEDVIDEO as default, then it shows nothing).

**NOTE:** I have also tried with someones else's Admob ID (which also uses UnityAds as rewarded video meditation) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the reward video ID? Right now there are two types. 
The old unity rewarded videos come with the reward string as "rewardedVideoZone" which can be found in the old unity ads dashboard website, while the new Unity ID is just "rewardedVideo" which is found in the New Unity Ads Dashboard.